# unable to setup ssldump on mac using homebrew

Tags: macos, homebrew

I just installed ssldump on a mac computeg using brew.  The installation process ran without reporting any issues (ssldump-0.9b3 already installed).  However, when I try running ssldump from the same prompt or a new terminal window, the error message I get is:

```
-bash: ssldump: command not found
```

Is there anything else that i need to do to make this work on a Mac El capitan (v10.11.6)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply using brew install ssldump did not work for me as ssldump was added in /usr/local/sbin (which was neither mentioned on /etc/paths nor in .bash_profile).  I ended up adding /usr/local/sbin to the .bash_profile and used sourced the file to enable the change.

```
cd ~
sudo vi .bash_profile
```

**add to the file:**

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:$PATH
&
source .bash_profile
```